# Where to find list postman collectionVariable

Tags: postman

i use a lot of `pm.collectionVariables.set()` to temporary store variable from another request an re-use it again
we can see a list of Environment and Global Variable
but I don't know where to find a list of the stored collectionVariables.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in collection's information.

[image]